# How to search on Flickr with advanced filters like portrait, > x mega pixel etc.?

Tags: search, flickr, photos, photo-sharing

Flickr has an advanced search page, but it does not allow to specify search filters like minimal mega pixels, minimal dimensions or orientation (portrait vs. landscape) etc. Is there is some **more advanced** search page available or something like that?

The advanced search of google images is truly advanced, it provides these features. But I noticed that restricting a google image search to flickr.com skips a lot of images in comparison to a search on flickr.com with the same search terms. Plus, it does not provide Flickr tag searches.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the [Yahoo advanced image search](http://images.search.yahoo.com/images/advanced?ei=UTF-8).

Set the site/domain to

> only from Flickr.com

hope this helps.